# How to use a custom heap with IMFSourceReader

Tags: c++, ms-media-foundation

In our application we are using an IMFSourceReader to handle the decode of a .mp4 file for us to play.

What we would like to do is reserve an amount of memory in the application and then configure the IMFSourceReader to use this reserved memory as its heap when it allocates the IMFSampleObjects.

I am wondering what might be the best way to try an achieve this. I believe that we will need to implement a custom media source as suggested in this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/writing-a-custom-media-source#generating-source-data and use the MFCreateSourceReaderFromMediaSource method. Is that correct?

Additionally I am still unclear on exactly where we would do the memory allocations. Will we need to create a new IMFMediaBuffer object as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think it is realistic to supply custom memory heap without re-implementing Media Foundation primitives behind your source reader media pipeline (also, in the context of the question it would be worth mentioning its details).

More importantly though, I suppose there is no real need or advantage in doing things this way. If you see increased memory pressure, it is highly unlikely that potential enormous effort in customization of memory allocator for primitives inside the source reader improves the situation. This is one of the reasons the feature does not exist in first place.

Comment: What do you mean by the Media Foundation primitives, is there a lot more to this than just media source and media buffer?

Our application uses a custom heap for all of its allocations, we have recently tested on a device with limited memory and encountered E_OUTOFMEMORY from the source reader, seemingly as its internal media source cache grows. However it we could point it to our custom heap there should be enough memory for it to operate there

Comment: Even though it might so happen that that indeed one of the pipeline elements wastes or leaks memory, the answer ^^^ remains valid. First, it does not look like custom allocator is exactly the solution. Second, for a problem of this kind (and it's a nasty one) you have to collect way more information. Third, there is still no offering for allocator override. And finally, even if you wanted to replace one of the pipeline elements, which is possible but unlikely in the context of this question, you need to narrow down the scope and attribute the problem to specific element.

Comment: @RomanR. i have a question regarding directshow and virtual camera  which unfortunately have remained  unanswered . i would really appreciate if  you could give an opinion regarding this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/66155154/2404125.