# How to stream video to a virtual camera

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-10, directshow

I looked up some sources and it seems that it is possible to build a virtual camera using [DirectShow VCam](https://github.com/roman380/tmhare.mvps.org-vcam).

But please forgive my ignorance, I have absolutely no idea how to use it in my project.

Specifically, my C++ program uses opencv to capture input from the camera, and then does some processing on the input. I want the processed video stream to be "output to a virtual camera".
I'm not sure if this description is accurate. Anyway, I want other apps (such as zoom that get input from the camera) to select the Virtual Cam as input to get my processed video stream.

Can I do this with DirectShow VCam? And how?

I am a beginner and my native language is not English. So I'm not sure if my formulation is clear. Please give me some replies, thanks!

##### Current situation

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66155154/virtual-camera-capture-image-frame-from-opencv-and-pass-to-directshow-filter-f) is exactly the same as mine, but haven't gotten any comments yet.

[The vcam project](https://github.com/roman380/tmhare.mvps.org-vcam/blob/main/Filters/Filters.cpp) has a `fillbuffer()` method from where the data is filled:

```cpp
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  This is the routine where we create the data being output by the Virtual
//  Camera device.
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
HRESULT CVCamStream::FillBuffer(IMediaSample *pms)
{
    REFERENCE_TIME rtNow;
    
    REFERENCE_TIME avgFrameTime = ((VIDEOINFOHEADER*)m_mt.pbFormat)->AvgTimePerFrame;

    rtNow = m_rtLastTime;
    m_rtLastTime += avgFrameTime;
    pms->SetTime(&rtNow, &m_rtLastTime);
    pms->SetSyncPoint(TRUE);

    BYTE *pData;
    long lDataLen;
    pms->GetPointer(&pData);
    lDataLen = pms->GetSize();
    for(int i = 0; i < lDataLen; ++i)
        pData[i] = rand();

    return NOERROR;
} // FillBuffer
```

Here it fills the buffer with random numbers `pData[i]=rand()`. So if I use my image data to fill, can I achieve what I want? but

- How can I determine that the size of the buffer and the size of the image match?
- What can I do if I want to keep updating the data of each frame?
- ...

Also, I tried filling the buffer with a constant `pData[i]=255` and it did work. When I use the Virtual Cam on zoom it's all white. But it caused the zoom process to freeze and the CPU and GPU to be fully loaded. I do not know why.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Streaming _to_ a virtual camera can make sense and is actually what the OP does want to do. Sometimes you have a program output you want to use as a camera "input".

Answer (score 1):

Microsofts "PowerToys for Windows" has a "Video Mute" for video conferencing. It does just that. It creates a "virtual camera" device and routes video from the actual camera device to the "virtual camera" - unless the user uses a system-wide hotkey to "mute" the video feed.

This sounds exactly what you want to do. So you might want to have a look at the "PowerToys" github repository: https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys

Comment: This might be difficult for me. I can't figure out this project and extract useful information from it.

I've updated my question, can you provide some more direct information?